# Validate the date and specify the Format of Date in java

Tags: java, validation, date

Can some body give ideas for the same in java

`I/p = 03/FEB/2012`

`O/p = dd/MMM/YYYY`

`I/p = FEB/03/YYYY`

`O/p = MMM/dd/YYYY`

I am trying to fetch the Date Formatter type from Date provided

Comment: did you mean you want Date Formate from given date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the best you can do is gather up a bunch of `SimpleDateFormat` instances and check whether each one can parse your input.  If it can, then return it.  Something like this:

```
private List<DateFormat> acceptedFormats = Arrays.asList(
     new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy"),
     new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy"));

public List<DateFormat> getFirstFormatForDate(String date) {
    for ( DateFormat fmt : acceptedFormats ) {
        try {
            fmt.parse(date);
            return fmt;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

There's no code in the world that can tell you whether the user intends `01/02/2012` to mean January 2nd or February 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Date formatter is required. Please refer below links for examples.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/formatdate.html

Comment: Hi
I require a process in java by which would the I/p date ("03/Feb/2012") provided should be parsed and return the correct Format as O/p
("dd/MMM/YYYY")



I/p = 03/FEB/2012

O/p = dd/MMM/YYYY

I/p = FEB/03/YYYY

O/p = MMM/dd/YYYY